# MATLAB custom colormap, accessible by name of color map as string (just as default color maps are)

Tags: matlab, colormap

With the default MATLAB color maps, many functions can access the maps either by the rgb array, or by a string with the same name as that rgb array. For instance, in the code below, either of the lines with the `colormap` function would plot as intended.

```
x = linspace(0, 255, 255);
y = linspace(0, 255, 255);
[X Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

figure, imagesc(x, y, X);
% colormap(jet); % either this line or the one below it works.
colormap('jet'); % either this line or the one above it works.
colorbar();
```

However, the same is not true for custom-defined colormaps - only accessing the rgb array works, and accessing the name of the rgb array as a string does not:

```
hex = ['#ff0000'; '#00ff00';];
vec = [100; 0];
raw = sscanf(hex','#%2x%2x%2x',[3, size(hex,1)] ).' / 255;
my_map = interp1(vec,raw,linspace(100, 0, 256),'pchip');

x = linspace(0, 255, 255);
y = linspace(0, 255, 255);
[X Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

figure, imagesc(x, y, X);
colormap(my_map); % this line works, the one below it does not.
colormap('my_map'); % this line does not work.
colorbar();
```

What can I do to make it so that I can plot my custom color map when it is accessed as a string, so that the line that does not work above would work?

(By the way, one of the reasons I want to do this is because I am using functions for which I cannot directly access the code, that take a string as an argument for a color map. So, in order to use those functions with custom color maps, I need my custom color maps to be accessible as strings, just as the default MATLAB color maps are.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the above doesn't work is because `colormap` uses the `feval`, so in the original post, the line that doesn't work (`colormap('my_map');`) gives the following error:

```
Error using feval
Undefined function or variable 'my_map'.
```

A way to get around this is to create a .m file in a folder in the MATLAB path that uses the `feval` function, and to save a mat file with the rgb colormap that it accesses. I.e., in a folder in the MATLAB path, make two files:

```
% file 1: my_map.m
function my_map_1 = my_map()
    load('my_map_mat');
    my_map = my_map_mat; % file 2: my_map_mat.mat is a mat file with rgb values for the custom colormap.
end
```

Below is a function I wrote which does this. I didn't clean it up much from my version of the function before posting, but the key parts are toward the bottom, starting with the line `eval([cmap_name '_mat = cmap_1;']);`

```
% cmap_name : name of custom colormap
% cmap_data : 1- or 3-column matrix, or name of text file with 1 or 3 columns, containing colormap data.
% by default, interpolates custom colormap to have 256 rgb values.

function cmap(cmap_name, cmap_data, varargin)

    pnames = {'output_folder', 'method', 'map_length'};
    dflts  = {'path\to\folder\in\MATLAB\path\where\you\want\to\store\custom\colormaps\', 'nearest', 256};

    [output_folder, method, map_length] = internal.stats.parseArgs(pnames, dflts, varargin{:});

    if ~ strcmp(cmap_name, lower(cmap_name))
        disp(['cmap_name changed from ' cmap_name 'to ' lower(cmap_name) '.']);
    end
    cmap_name = lower(cmap_name); % Windows has issues if you don't do this

    if ~ (any(ismember(output_folder(1 : end - 1), regexp(path, pathsep, 'Split'))) || strcmp(output_folder(1 : end - 1), pwd))
        error('output folder must be in present working directory or MATLAB path. To add it to MATLAB path, use addpath function.');
    end

    if strcmp(class(cmap_data), 'char')
        fid = fopen(cmap_data);
        cmap_1 = textscan(fid, '%f');
        cmap_1 = cmap_1{1};
        fclose(fid);
    elseif strcmp(class(cmap_data), 'double')
        cmap_1 = cmap_data;
    else
        error('cmap_data must be double arr, or name of text file containing doubles.')
    end

    if min(flat(cmap_1)) < 0 || max(flat(cmap_1)) > 1
        error('cmap_data must not contain values below 0 or above 1.');
    end

    cmap_size = size(cmap_1);

    if ~ ismember(cmap_size(2), [1 3])
        error('cmap_data must be array or name of text file with either 1 column or 3 columns.');
    end

    if isequal(cmap_size(2), 1)
        cmap_1 = [cmap_1 cmap_1 cmap_1];
    end

    if ~ (cmap_size(1) == map_length)
        cmap_1 = interp1(1:length(cmap_1), cmap_1, linspace(1, length(cmap_1), map_length), method);
    end

    eval([cmap_name '_mat = cmap_1;']);
    save([output_folder cmap_name '_mat.mat'], [cmap_name '_mat']);

    fid = fopen([output_folder cmap_name '.m'], 'w');
    function_str = {
        ['function my_map = ' cmap_name '()']...
        ['    load(''' cmap_name '_mat'');']...
        ['    my_map = ' cmap_name '_mat;']...
        ['end']...
        };
    for i = 1:length(function_str)
        fprintf(fid, '%s\n', strcat(function_str{i}));
    end
    fclose(fid);

end
```

So now, this can be used e.g., as follows:

```
hex = ['#ff0000'; '#00ff00';];
vec = [100; 0];
raw = sscanf(hex','#%2x%2x%2x',[3, size(hex,1)] ).' / 255;
my_map = interp1(vec,raw,linspace(100, 0, 256),'pchip');
cmap('my_map', my_map);

x = linspace(0, 255, 255);
y = linspace(0, 255, 255);
[X Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

figure, imagesc(x, y, X);
colormap(my_map); % this line works, as does the line below it.
colormap('my_map'); % this line works, as does the line above it.
colorbar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some fast, dirty and dangerous way to achieve this would be:

```
%Code that will kinda work
try colormap(S); catch,colormap(eval(S));
```

Note that `eval` is a security issue because it will execute the code regardless of what is inside. Take these values for `S` for instance : `S = '! rm -Rf *';` or `S = 'delete(''*'')'`, calling `eval(S)` will delete the content of current directory.

A perhaps better way is:

```
function colormap_custom(S)
    % These are default maps in R2014a, but it may change with the version => maintenance hell in the making
    defaultMaps = {'autumn', 'bone', 'colorcube', 'cool', 'copper', 'flag', 'gray', 'hot', 'hsv', 'jet', 'lines', 'pink', 'prism', 'spring', 'summer', 'white', 'winter'};

    assert(ischar(S),'S is expected to be a char array');
    if any(strcmp(S,defaultMaps))
    colormap(S);
    elseif ~isempty(who(S)) %Check that S is actually the name of a variable
        tmpS = eval(S);
        assert(isnumeric(tmpS) && size(tmpS,2)==3,'S : n-by-3 numeric array expected');
        colormap(tmpS)
    else error('unknow colormap value for S')
    end
end
```

Then:

```
mymap=rand(64,3); %random RGB colormap
colormap_custom('jet');     % gives colormap jet
colormap_custom('mymap');   % gives custom colormap
colormap_custom('yourmap'); % error
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get the error that is built into the function, `'unknow colormap value for S'` when I try using it. However, I came up with a function that solves the problem, I will post it as an answer below.